# In React, onclick in child component is not bindin

Tags: reactjs, onclick

In my child compenent, I'm trying to add an `onclick` event to my html and when I transpile I get an error:

> "bundle.min.js:35884 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined".

I've tried defining the called function in the parent component but that doesn't work either. It's the `onClick={playMusic}` bit that's giving me the bother.

```
import {Component} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router';

class Thumbs extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.playMusic = this.Playmusic.bind(this);
    }

    playMusic() {
        var audio = new Audio(media_item.href);
        audio.play();
    }

render() {
        const {href, nasa_id} = this.props
        if (nasa_id !== '000') {
            return <Link to={`/asset/${nasa_id}`}><img src={href} width="100" height="100"/></Link>
        } else {
            return <img
                    src="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/images/thumb/gramophone_108546017_250.jpg?version=3.1.118"
                    width="100" height="100"
                    onClick={playMusic}
                    />
        }
    }
}

export default Thumbs
```

Comment: Error is in this line: `this.playMusic = this.Playmusic.bind(this);`. Change to `this.playMusic = this.playMusic.bind(this);`

Comment: Thanks, Madhavan. That and changing "onClick={playMusic}" to "onClick={this.playMusic}" did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fat arrow function and get rid of the function binding in the constructor. Change the **playMusic()** method as below

```
playMusic = () => {
    var audio = new Audio(media_item.href);
    audio.play();
}
```

After that remove `this.playMusic = this.Playmusic.bind(this);` from the constructor and in the render method use `onClick={this.playMusic}`.